Leaning on a bike while turning: how can moments be balanced?
Consider a cyclist turning a corner. The cyclist will lean, so that the sum of friction $F$, normal reaction $N$ and weight $W$ will equal the centripetal force.
However, I cannot understand how the cyclist does not rotate to the ground. For the bike not to rotate to the ground, the sum of torques about the point of contact between the bike and the ground (point $P$) must be zero. However, it is not zero. The normal reaction force $N$ and the friction $F$ produce a zero torque, as they are applied exactly at the point of contact. The weight $W$ instead does provide torque, because it is applied at the center of mass, which is at a non-zero distance to the point of contact $P$. So there is a net torque and the bike should rotate.
For clarity, consider the image below:

It's complicated. Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmDTTVvmm5M

Thank you for the reference to the interesting video, but that’s more complicated than necessary (and talks about topics more complicated than necessary).
The answer by BowlOfRed is more to the point. Thanks!

If BowlOfRed's explanation were the only factor then a turning bike would be very unstable, since any deviation from the ideal angle of banking would be magnified by positive feedback.

You are right, and the lecture is helpful. I just meant to say for my purposes I was looking for a more approximate kind of explanation. Thanks!


For the bike not to rotate to the ground, the sum of torques about the point of contact between the bike and the ground (point ) must be zero.

This is only necessarily true for a non-accelerating body in an inertial frame.

Bike Frame

In the non-inertial frame where the bike is at rest, a centrifugal force appears.   When added to your FBD above, it zeroes the total torque.

Ground Frame

"non-zero torque implies rotation" is a simplification that is true for non-accelerating objects.  A more general statement is that "non-zero torque implies change in angular momentum".
For an accelerating object, that change in angular momentum can be solely from it's changing translational velocity and no rotation is required.   That's happening for the bicycle.   If you calculate the angular momentum as it moves away from $P$, you'll find it exactly matches the unbalanced torque.


However, I cannot understand how the cyclist does not rotate to the
ground.

To show why the cyclist does not rotate, it’s not necessary to analyze this in the non inertial (accelerating) frame of the cyclist requiring introducing the fictitious centrifugal force.
In the inertial ground frame we can relocate the friction force $F$ parallel to its line of action to act on the center of gravity (COG) of the bike (the point where $W$ acts) as long as we add a clockwise couple (pure moment) about point $P$ to cancel the torque created about $P$ due to relocating $F$. See the Figures below. The net effect is we now have a clockwise moment about $P$ that balances the counter clockwise moment of $W$ about $P$ so that the cyclist does not fall.
Hope this helps.

